# "Human motives are an involved affair" - meaning in a sample text

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

This is a paragraph (13th) from [An Egyptian Hornet](https://doyleandmacdonald.com/l_hornet.htm), a short story by Algernon Blackwood:

> Human motives, even in the professedly holy, **are an involved affair at any time**. Just now, in the Rev. James Milligan, they were quite inextricably mixed. **He claims this explanation, at any rate, in excuse of his abominable subsequent behaviour.**

I understand the language here but I think I do not get the point of both parts in bold. How should I understand it?

Comment: It will be better if you provide the source.

Comment: @lee Algernon Blackwood - An Egyptian Hornet.

Comment: I think it's at best "clumsy" phrasing (partly because of the plurality clash between ***motives*** and ***affair***). Much better would have been something like ***are invariably complex matters***.

Comment: Human motives (the reasons why people do things) are very complicated at any time... This is the excuse he gives for (whatever bad action he did later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Human motives can not be easily understood because they are always very complicated.
2. He insists on this explanation anyway to excuse his abominable following behaviors.